# How to move horizontal data to vertical line items?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I created an Excel table with different Inventory items saved in different physical locations. This table was compiled from various Inventory tables.

**My table looks like this:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Item Name|Item Description|Qty loc1|Qty loc2|Qty loc3|Qty loc4|Qty loc5|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Item 1   |Item 1 Descr    |       2|       4|       5|       3|       1|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Item 2   |Item 2 Descr    |       8|        |       5|        |       1|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Item 3   |Item 3 Descr    |        |       4|        |       3|       1|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Item 4   |Item 4 Descr    |       4|        |       5|        |       1|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Item 5   |Item 5 Descr    |        |        |        |        |        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Item 6   |Item 6 Descr    |      1 |        |        |        |      3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**I would like my table to look like this:**

```
----------------------------------------------
|Item Name|Item Description|Qty     |Loc Name|
----------------------------------------------
|Item 1   |Item 1 Descr    |       2|    Loc1|
----------------------------------------------
|Item 1   |Item 1 Descr    |       4|    Loc2|
----------------------------------------------
|Item 1   |Item 1 Descr    |       5|    Loc3|
----------------------------------------------
|Item 1   |Item 1 Descr    |       3|    Loc4|
----------------------------------------------
|Item 1   |Item 1 Descr    |       1|    Loc5|
----------------------------------------------
|Item 2   |Item 2 Descr    |       8|    Loc1|
----------------------------------------------
|Item 2   |Item 2 Descr    |       5|    Loc3|
----------------------------------------------
|Item 2   |Item 2 Descr    |       1|    Loc5|
----------------------------------------------
|Item 3   |Item 3 Descr    |       4|    Loc2|
----------------------------------------------
|Item 3   |Item 3 Descr    |       3|    Loc4|
----------------------------------------------
|Item 3   |Item 3 Descr    |       1|    Loc5|
----------------------------------------------
```

and so on...

**In this case, some locations DO NOT have any items and hence that cell is blank.
An item should only have a line if there is any inventory in any location.**

I tried making a separate worksheet in the same workbook to be able to pull cell values but that didn't work. What would be the best approach to tackle this? What would be the formula for this?

Comment: Search on google for power query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Unpivot Using Power Query

[image]

**Do It Yourself**

- Right-click on your table and in the pop-up menu select *Get Data from Table/Range...*.

[image]

- The Power Query Editor opens.

[image]

- Ctrl+left-click `Item Description` to add it to the selection.

[image]

- Right-click `Item Description` and in the pop-up menu select *Unpivot Other Columns*.

[image]

- Left-click `Value` and drag it to the left so the column switches places with the `Attributes` column.

[image]

- Right-click `Value` and in the pop-up menu select *Rename...* and rename the column to `Qty`.

[image]

- Similarly, right-click `Attributes` and in the pop-up menu select *Rename...* and rename the column to `Loc Name`.

[image]

- Right-click `Loc Name` and in the pop-up menu select *Replace Values...* and in the *Replace Values* dialog, in the *Value To Find* text box, enter `Qty`  (note the trailing space) and press *OK*.

[image]

[image]

- Right-click `Loc Name` and in the pop-up menu select *Transform* and in the *Transform* pop-up menu select *Capitalize Each Word*.

[image]

- Select *Close & Load* in the ribbon.

[image]

**Use the M-Code**

- Right-click on your table and in the pop-up menu select *Get Data from Table/Range...*.
- The Power Query Editor opens.
- In the ribbon, select *Advanced Editor* and replace the current code with the following one (copy the code, click in the box and use Ctrl+A and Ctrl+V).
- Adjust the table name and the column names if necessary.
- Select *Done*.

```vb
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Item Name", type text}, {"Item Description", type text}, {"Qty loc1", Int64.Type}, {"Qty loc2", Int64.Type}, {"Qty loc3", Int64.Type}, {"Qty loc4", Int64.Type}, {"Qty loc5", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Item Name", "Item Description"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Item Name", "Item Description", "Value", "Attribute"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Value", "Qty"}, {"Attribute", "Loc Name"}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Renamed Columns","Qty ","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Loc Name"}),
    #"Capitalized Each Word" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value",{{"Loc Name", Text.Proper, type text}})
in
    #"Capitalized Each Word"
```

[image]

- Select *Close & Load* in the ribbon.

Comment: This seems like a great idea. I've tried it but after I clicked on 'Close & Load' in the ribbon, I'm see a 'ExternalData_1: Getting Data...' message and on the right it says, 'Table1 2,825 rows loaded'. It has been this way for a few hours now and nothing has changed.
Perhaps, I have too many records?